# How Can I get current document by using the user UID?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing a Flutter app wherein, upon user creation, authentication credentials are established.

[image]

Subsequently, a unique document ID is generated in Firestore to associate with this user.

My objective is to dynamically retrieve this user-specific document from Firestore, enabling access to and utilization of the associated variables.

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _fetchData(String userId) async {
    try {
      // Use the user's UID directly to construct the document reference
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(userId)
              .get();

      print(('user id: $userId');

      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        return documentSnapshot.data()!;
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist for User ID: $userId');
        return {};
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching data: $e');
      return {};
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically retrieve this user-specific document"? Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: when the user creates an account and then goes to the home page I want to tell him hello {his name} I can't get access to the name from Firestore.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Firebase doesn't automatically create any document in Firestore for a new user. So if such a document exists, it's because something in your application code created it - and we can't see that code. Please either show the code that created the user-specific document, or a screenshot of said document (from the Firestore console) that makes it clear how the document is associated with the user.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the screenshot. What doesn't work about the code you shared? Is there an error message? If not, what does `print('user id: $userId');` output - as well as any other `print` statements fro your code?

Comment: it gives me the UID in the Authentication